# Snowflake & SQLAlchemy "unexpected 'UNIQUE'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm running a python db migration script (Flask-Migrate) and have added the alembic.ddl.imp import DefaultImpl to get around the first set of errors but now I'm getting the following. I'm trying to use this script to set up my tables and database in snowflake. What am I missing? Everything seems to be working and I can't seem to find any help on this particular error in the snowflake documentation. I would assume that the snowflake sqlalchemy connector would address the creation of a unique index.

The script so far does create several of the tables, but when it gets to this part it throws the error.

```
> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError:
> (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 001003 (42000): SQL
> compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 7 unexpected
> 'UNIQUE'. [SQL: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_flicket_users_token ON
> flicket_users (token)] (Background on this error at:
> http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Answer (score 2):

Snowflake does not have `INDEX` objects, so any `CREATE ... INDEX` statement will fail.

With Snowflake, you have to trust the database to organize your data with micro partitions and build a good access plan for your queries.

You will feel uneasy at first, but eventually stop worrying.

Bleeding edge solutions will require monitoring/tuning performance using the query log, however.
Nothing new here.

Comment: That's what I figured, but why would the sqlalchemy connector for Snowflake allow a CREATE INDEX statement to be created. It defeats the purpose of using Sqlalchemy. 

Comment: The Snowflake connector is a 3rd party addition, perhaps they've not had time to smooth out such edges. On the other hand why would they make a special case, when the simple solution is to not use indexes.

Comment: Well Snowflake has an SQLAlchemy connector so I would think that their connector would just convert anything regarding index creation into NOT creating an index. I posted about it in their github and someone is looking into it. I'll update this if/when it gets addressed :)